# TypeScript output difference with lambda functions and normal functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code:

```
var initChannelEvents = () =>
    $("#channels a").click(
        (eventObject: JQueryEventObject) => setActiveChannel(this)
    );
```

And this:

```
var initChannelEvents2 = () =>
    $("#channels a").click(
        function (eventObject: JQueryEventObject) {
            setActiveChannel(this);
        });
```

The output is:

```
var _this = this;
var initChannelEvents = function () {
    return $("#channels a").click(function (eventObject) { 
        return setActiveChannel(_this); });
    };
```

and this:

```
var initChannelEvents2 = function () {
    return $("#channels a").click(function (eventObject) {
        setActiveChannel(this);
    });
};
```

**UPDATE:**

TS:

```
var initChannelEvents2 = () =>
    $("#channels a").click(
        (eventObject: JQueryEventObject) => {
            setActiveChannel(this);
        }
    );
```

JS:

```
var _this = this;
var initChannelEvents2 = function () {
    return $("#channels a").click(function (eventObject) {
        setActiveChannel(_this);
    });
};
```

I understand the output of the second snippet and that is what I expected. I don't understand the output of the first. I would expect them to be the same.

Why are they different? What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lambda/arrow functions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-lambdas-and-using-39this39) (`() => ...`) in TypeScript ([and in JavaScript ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) have some additional behaviour beyond standard function expressions, requiring some additional code when compiling to JavaScript ES3/ES5.

```
var _this = this;
```

The value of `this` within the lambda is automatically bound/saved to the value of `this` outside of the lambda. A normal function would get its value for `this` based on how it's called.

```
return setActiveChannel(_this);
```

If the body of a lambda function is a single expression (not a block `{ ... }`), the value of that expression will be automatically returned, without an explicit `return` statement.